# C# EF6 conditional property selection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose I have code-first model:

```
public class FooBar
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [MaxLength(254)]
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

And method to retrieve some subsets of data of rows:

```
public IQueryable<FooBar> GetDataQuery(bool includeTitle, bool includeDescription)
{
    var query = ctx.FooBars.AsNoTracking().Where(Id > 123);
    //how to inlcude/exclude???
    return query;
}
```

The question is how to build query with specific fields without hardcoding anonymous types? Basically, I want to tell SQL query builder to build query with specified fields, without post filtering that on client. So if I exclude Description - it will not be sent over wire.

Also, had experience like this:

```
public IQueryable<FooBar> GetDataQuery(bool includeTitle, bool includeDescription)
{
    var query = ctx.FooBars.AsNoTracking().Where(Id > 123);
    query = query.Select(x=> new
    {  
         Id = x.Id
         Title = includeTitle ? x.Title : null,
         Description = includeDescription ? x.Description : null,
    })
    .MapBackToFooBarsSomehow();//this will fail, I know, do not want to write boilerplate to hack this out, just imagine return type will be correctly retrieved
    return query;
}
```

But this will send over wire *includeTitle*, *includeDescription* properties as SQL parameters for *EXEC* and query will be inefficient in most cases compared to simple non-conditional anonymous query without this clutter - but writing every possible permutation of anonymous structure is not an option.

**PS**: in reality there is big list of "include/exclude" properties, I just presented two for simplicity.

**UPDATE:**

Inspired by *@reckface* answer, I wrote extension for those who want to achieve fluent-like execution and mapping to entity at the end of their query:

```
public static class CustomSqlMapperExtension
{
    public sealed class SpecBatch<T>
    {
        internal readonly List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> Items = new List<Expression<Func<T, object>>>();

        internal SpecBatch()
        {
        }

        public SpecBatch<T> Property(Expression<Func<T, object>> selector, bool include = true)
        {
            if (include)
            {
                Items.Add(selector);
            }
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static List<T> WithCustom<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Action<SpecBatch<T>> configurator)
    {
        if (source == null)
            return null;

        var batch = new SpecBatch<T>();
        configurator(batch);
        if (!batch.Items.Any())
            throw new ArgumentException("Nothing selected from query properties", nameof(configurator));

        LambdaExpression lambda = CreateSelector(batch);
        var rawQuery = source.Provider.CreateQuery(
            Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable),
                nameof(Queryable.Select),
                new[]
                {
                    source.ElementType,
                    lambda.Body.Type
                }, 
                source.Expression, 
                Expression.Quote(lambda))
        );
        return rawQuery.ToListAsync().Result.ForceCast<T>().ToList();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> ForceCast<T>(this IEnumerable<object> enumer)
    {
        return enumer.Select(x=> Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)).ShallowAssign(x)).Cast<T>();
    }

    private static object ShallowAssign(this object target, object source)
    {
        if (target == null || source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var type = target.GetType();
        var data = source.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Select(e => new
            {
                e.Name,
                Value = e.GetValue(source)
            });
        foreach (var property in data)
        {
            type.GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(target, property.Value);
        }
        return target;
    }

    private static LambdaExpression CreateSelector<T>(SpecBatch<T> batch)
    {
        var input = "new(" + string.Join(", ", batch.Items.Select(GetMemberName<T>)) + ")";
        return System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(typeof(T), null, input);
    }

    private static string GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
    {
        var body = expr.Body;
        if (body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        {
            body = ((UnaryExpression) body).Operand;
        }
        var memberExpr = body as MemberExpression;
        var propInfo = memberExpr.Member as PropertyInfo;
        return propInfo.Name;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Topic
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public byte[] Logo { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            ctx.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;

            var query = (ctx.Topics ?? Enumerable.Empty<Topic>()).AsQueryable();
            query = query.Where(x => x.Title != null);
            var result = query.WithCustom(
                cfg => cfg                         //include whitelist config
                    .Property(x => x.Author, true) //include
                    .Property(x => x.Title, false) //exclude
                    .Property(x=> x.Id, true));    //include

        }
    }
}
```

Important to mention that those entities can't be used in EF, until you explicitly attach them.

Comment: That's quite complicated (surprisingly) in EF. Also, even the method listed in your question will not work, because `MapBackToFooBars` will throw something about "The entity or complex type cannot be constructed..."

Comment: Yes, I know, just didn't want to write mapping back explicitly in example code. Still, maybe one can somehow intercept query building?

Comment: I mean it will fail for other reason (because you cannot do `Select(x => new SomeType {...})` where SomeType is mapped entity).

Comment: `bool` parameters in method head are great indicators for too much logic and/or missing SoC (Separation of Concerns). An approach could be to have a private method that returns kind of "basic query" and to use it in more concrete methods like `GetFooBar` (all properties), `GetFooBarWithoutTitle` or `GetFooBarWithoutDescription`. It's not nice but could fulfil your needs. Furthermore insteaf of anonyme types I would use defined ones.

Comment: In SQL you can choose what to select, still it is used even though it is bad practice to choose whatever you want, and yes, I know that you can hack this out by separating subsets into concrete types, but this will not work in my case. Properties MUST be conditional. All of them. When numbers of those bool will be represented as bitmap - I don't think you will permutate GetFooBarWithout<N1,N2,N3, ... >

Comment: @Evk, I know that this error occurs, I added it only to show example.

Comment: This doesn't look like the actual code in use. `.Where(Id > 123);`? Why would that even compile unless you have an extension method on whatever it is that `.AsNoTracking()` returns for `.Where(bool)` and `Id` is an identifier in scope for `GetDataQuery`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen you are nitpicking, I think it's quite clear that OP means `Where(x => x.Id > 123)`. And that's not even related to the question.

Comment: I would expect something like `db.Foobars.Select(fb => new Foobar() { Name = fb.Name}).ToList()` to render a correct query; but I'm currently unable to doublecheck that fact.

Comment: This would be so much easier if you just sent a raw query. Then you're in full control of what's sent over the wire. One of the reasons I stopped using EF a few years ago. Plus it was dead slow and the queries weren't always as straightforward as the ones written in pure SQL.

Comment: @silkfire: One shouldn't use EF for increased performance. It's good to make that clear and understood. But the main benefit of using EF is the fact that you _don't_ need to write SQL or have direct control over the database. If you don't mind writing SQL and prefer direct control (pro: optimization, con: more work), then the use case for EF simply doesn't apply to you; rather than EF itself being bad to use.

Comment: @Flater Fair point I suppose. Btw, *optimalization* is not a word :)

Comment: @silkfire: Damn my Dutch native language! Little things like that slip through :)

Comment: Raw queries is out of question just because they give you too much freedom for simple data-storage DSL. They are not prone to errors, hard to implement and support in my case. I use them only for business specific rebindings and transformations over schema and data or if I want to lemon-squezze performance which happens 1 time for every 10 thousand lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) for this very successfully. You can pass a string 
as the select statement in the following format: `.Select("new(Title, Description)")`

So your example would become:

```
// ensure you import the System.Linq.Dynamic namespace
public IQueryable<FooBar> GetDataQuery(bool includeTitle, bool includeDescription)
{
    // build a list of columns, at least 1 must be selected, so maybe include an Id
    var columns = new List<string>(){nameof(FooBar.Id)};        
    if (includeTitle)
        columns.Add(nameof(FooBar.Title));
    if (includeDescription)
        columns.Add(nameof(FooBar.Description));
    // join said columns
    var select = $"new({string.Join(", ", columns)})";
    var query = ctx.FooBars.AsQueryable()
        .Where(f => f.Id > 240)
        .Select(select)
        .OfType<FooBar>();
    return query;
}
```

**EDIT**

Turns out OfType() may not work here. If that's the case, here's a poor man's extension method:

```
// not ideal, but it fits your constraints
var query = ctx.FooBars.AsQueryable()
            .Where(f => f.Id > 240)
            .Select(select)
            .ToListAsync().Result
            .Select(r => new FooBar().Fill(r));

public static T Fill<T>(this T item, object element)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var data = element.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Select(e => new
        {
            e.Name,
            Value = e.GetValue(element)
        });
    foreach (var property in data)
    {
        type.GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(item, property.Value);
    }
    return item;
}
```

**Update**

But wait there's more!

```
var query = ctx.FooBars
    .Where(f => f.Id > 240)
    .Select(select)
    .ToJson() // using Newtonsoft.JSON, I know, I know, awful. 
    .FromJson<IEnumerable<FooBar>>()
    .AsQueryable(); // this is no longer valid or necessary
return query;

public static T FromJson<T>(this string json)
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    using (var sr = new StringReader(json))
    using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        var result = serializer.Deserialize<T>(jr);
        return result;
    }
}

public static string ToJson(this object data)
{
    if (data == null)
        return null;
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    return json;
}
```

**Results**

[image: Generated SQL]

[image: Generated results]

[image: With Navigation properties (Counting)]

[image]

Comment: O_o...wow, I will look at your solution if it is really works. Thanks!

Comment: I updated to add option to use serialisation. Mainly because, once you start dealing with dynamic projections you no longer have any actual type information. Update us with what you decided in the end.

Comment: You checked generated SQL query? Is it realy partially filled?

Comment: Yes. I'll upload screenshot.

Comment: You, sir, is awesome, your answer will be stoned in my personal collection. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no clean way to do that in EF. You can use some workarounds of various ugliness, below is one. It will work only if you are not going to update\attach\delete returned entities, which I assume is fine for this use case.

Suppose we want to include only properties "ID" and "Code". We need to construct expression of this form:

```
fooBarsQuery.Select(x => new FooBar {ID = x.ID, Code = x.Code))
```

We can do that manually like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> IncludeOnly<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, params string[] properties) {
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var bindings = new List<MemberBinding>();

    foreach (var propName in properties) {
        var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);
        bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(prop, Expression.Property(arg, prop)));
    }
    // our select, x => new T {Prop1 = x.Prop1, Prop2 = x.Prop2 ...}
    var select = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(T)), bindings), arg);
    return query.Select(select);
}
```

But if we actually try that:

```
// some test entity I use
var t = ctx.Errors.IncludeOnly("ErrorID", "ErrorCode", "Duration").Take(10).ToList();
```

It will fail with exception

> The entity or complex type ... cannot be constructed
>   in a LINQ to Entities query

So, `new SomeType` is illegal in `Select` if `SomeType` is type of mapped entity.

But what if we have a type inherited from entity and use that?

```
public class SomeTypeProxy : SomeType {}
```

Well, then it will work. So we need to get such proxy type somewhere. It's easy to generate it at runtime with built-in tools, since all we need is to inherit from some type and that's all.

With that in mind, our method becomes:

```
static class Extensions {
    private static ModuleBuilder _moduleBuilder;
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> _proxies = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

    static Type GetProxyType<T>() {
        lock (typeof(Extensions)) {
            if (_proxies.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
                return _proxies[typeof(T)];

            if (_moduleBuilder == null) {
                var asmBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
                    new AssemblyName("ExcludeProxies"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

                _moduleBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(
                    asmBuilder.GetName().Name, false);
            }

            // Create a proxy type
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = _moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeof(T).Name + "Proxy",
                TypeAttributes.Public |
                TypeAttributes.Class,
                typeof(T));

            var type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
            // cache it
            _proxies.Add(typeof(T), type);
            return type;
        }
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> IncludeOnly<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, params string[] properties) {
        var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        var bindings = new List<MemberBinding>();

        foreach (var propName in properties) {
            var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);
            bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(prop, Expression.Property(arg, prop)));
        }

        // modified select, (T x) => new TProxy {Prop1 = x.Prop1, Prop2 = x.Prop2 ...}
        var select = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(GetProxyType<T>()), bindings), arg);
        return query.Select(select);
    }
}
```

And now it works fine and generates select sql query with only included fields. It really returns a list of proxy types, but that's not a problem, since proxy type inherits from your query type. Thought as I said before - you cannot attach\update\remove it from context.

Of course you can also modify this method to exclude, accept property expressions instead of pure strings and so on, that's just idea proof code.

Comment: Wow, good work and thanks to point me in right direction! I only read entities in this mode but proxy is a bit too much. Will try to bypass that EF check and post solution if I find something.

Comment: Why proxy is too much? Many libs (including EF itself) generate types at runtime. In this case number of generated types is small and they are cached, so seems more or less fine.

Comment: Syntax sugar, my friend, just syntax sugar. Though, I agree with you, this can be easly solved by pregeneration =) Also, I just don't like situations where you need to pregenerate something and don't have full control over it (not error prone, just like any service reference proxy and etc).

Comment: @eocron I think what Evk suggests is the cheapest possible workaround. What about bypassing EF check, it is [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/946b7592fedcce669d9cfc771af38540def02eac/src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/ELinq/ExpressionConverter.cs#L1054) and called from [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/946b7592fedcce669d9cfc771af38540def02eac/src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/ELinq/Translator.cs#L830) ...

Comment: ... and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/946b7592fedcce669d9cfc771af38540def02eac/src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/ELinq/Translator.cs#L948), i.e. both `new Something` internal expression translators, so good luck :)

Comment: @eocron but here you have full control and it's not error prone, because types are generated at runtime automatically (no way to forget) and generated by you (full control). Proxy is also very simple (zero functionality, just inherited from type). Still a hack though.

Comment: @Evk Btw, if it wasn't clear, my previous comment is supporting your answer. If you follow the code links, you'll see that they are in places that cannot be intercepted / skipped in any way.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes it's clear right from the first phrase in your first comment :) I replied to old eocron comment above. Pity that such quite basic functionality is still not implemented. Though I assume it's not that easy to make it work without pitfalls, given "unit of work" nature of EF.

Comment: Well, It is quite easy (I decompiled some linked sources, and see that this can be done, without proxy if one have access to source). Might throw a ticket to developer or support one.

Comment: @Evk It has to be something related to tracking / proxy creation implementation details for "entity" types I guess. Interestingly, this limitation is removed in EF Core. But as you know, currently it has a lot of other pitfalls, so no full happiness :)

Comment: I too, thought about migrating to EF Core 2. But just for this particular feature....man, EF is hard.